# Grails rest-api PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer bean not present

Tags: grails

I want generate a html inside a controller or service but the bean "PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer" has not present in the application context.
I think the problem is the profile rest-api, do you know how initialize the bean?
Do you have some idea?

Thanks
Mauro

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
You need to add this dependency
implementation "org.grails.plugins:gsp"

Thanks